# Tkinter - multithreading or multiprocessing in for loop

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter, multiprocessing

I would like to optimize my program. In short, it is used to unzip huge tar.gz archive (5 gb+) or extract some file from it (approx. 20k) based on input.

The main problem I am facing right now is that window is not responding, but I really need it to work properly. I have read about multiprocessing and multithreading, but not sure how to apply it on my code.

Could you, please, help me with it?

Here are 2 my functions for unziping:

```
def unzip_tar_gz(self, ARES_tar_gz):
        row             = 22 #used for GUI
        self.debug_output("Unzip", row, "Start: ")
        tarfile_ARES    = tarfile.open(ARES_tar_gz)
        
        #counters for progress bar
        self.counter    = 0
        self.maxcount   = 1200000
        
        #extract
        for member in tarfile_ARES.getmembers():
            self.update_idletasks()
            member.name = os.path.basename(member.name)
            result      = re.search("(.*).xml", member.name)
            res         = result.group(1)
            r           = res[:-1]
            num         = int(r)
            tarfile_ARES.extract(member, self.get_folder(num))
            self.counter+=1
            
            #debug
            if self.counter%100000 == 0:
                row += 1
                self.debug_output("extract 100k", row, "Success")

        #after extract, closing
        showinfo("Success", message="The execution was successfully completed.")
        self.pb.stop()
        self.destroy()
```

and

```
def unzip_changes(self, delta_file_arr, inputARES):
    row            = 22 #used for GUI

    #debug
    self.debug_output("Unzip changes", row, "Start: ")

    tarfile_ARES = tarfile.open(inputARES)
    time_not_found = date.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    file_not_found = open(self.logs_path + time_not_found + '.log', 'w')

    #counters for progress bar
    self.counter    = 0
    self.maxcount   = 22000

    #extract
    for name in delta_file_arr:
        self.update_idletasks()
        self.counter +=1
        try:
            member      = tarfile_ARES.getmember(name)
            member.name = os.path.basename(member.name)
            result      = re.search("(.*).xml", member.name)
            res         = result.group(1)
            r           = res[:-1]
            num         = int(r)
            tarfile_ARES.extract(member, self.get_folder(num))
        except:
            result         = re.search("./VYSTUP/DATA/(.*).xml", name)
            res            = result.group(1)
            file_not_found.write(res + "\n")
            continue
    #after extract, closing
    self.pb.stop()
    showinfo("Success", message="The execution was successfully completed.")
    file_not_found.close()
    self.destroy()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a thread for each function you want run because if you don't, the tkinter window will freeze until the function finish for example. So use:

```
import threading
```

Here an example with a button:

```
Button = tk.Button(text='Thread',command=lambda: threading.Thread(target=my_function).start())
```

if you use class:

```
self.Button = tk.Button(self, text='Thread',command=lambda: threading.Thread(target=self.my_function).start())
```

Comment: Hello @Malou, thank you for your response! The functions are not run parallely, the user chooses if he wants to unzip the whole file or just part of it. So, when he clicks button "Start", it runs first or second function. Is it possible to apply multithreading for tkinter and "backend" separately? If I understood correctly, your solution is regarding running the functions using the button, am I right?